# rails 4 retrive model with association (as nested attrs) in hash

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord, nested

> pseudo

```
model User
  has_many :books
model Book
  belongs_to :user
```

What i want is

```
pseudo User.first.with(:books)


result => Hash {user:  {name: "john_doe", 
                  books: {0: {title: "book"}}}}
```

How can i achieve this?

```
EDIT
```

i'm almost there: User.preload(:books).first -> retrives model with nested,
but now how to serialilze it as above?
   EDIT
ve done it!

```
user = User.preload(:books).first
hash = user.as_json
books = user.books
x = Hash[(0...books.size).zip books]
hash[:books] = x
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**app/models/user.rb**

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :books

  def as_json(options = nil)
    super({ only: [:id, :name], include: :books })
  end
end
```

With that you can use `as_json` like this:

```
>> User.first.as_json
=> {"id"=>1, "name"=>"john_doe", "books"=>[
   {"user_id"=>1, "id"=>1, "title"=>"book", 
    "created_at"=>Fri, 06 Feb 2015 09:25:12 UTC +00:00, 
    "updated_at"=>Fri, 06 Feb 2015 09:25:12 UTC +00:00}]}
>>
```

There are also some gems which provide similar results. Have a look at http://robots.thoughtbot.com/better-serialization-less-as-json for more information.

Comment: great and correct answer! (sry can't upvote because of insufficient rep)

Comment: Thanks! Please accept the answer (that's a button below the up- and downvoting button). Anybody who asks a question can accept the answer. Up- and Downvoting is just the next step after that.